# Calculate average using AVG function for multiple numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure that I used the correct title, I will edit the question if I will understand a little bit more about the topic.

Now I tried to test MySQL's `AVG()` function and tried the query:

```
SELECT AVG(1,2,3)
```

I expected that this will give me `2` as a result. But I've get en error as `AVG()` intended to receive a column name as single parameter. I can not imagine that I will need this thing anywhere beyond this very artificial example but I believe that I will understand SQL language better if I will be able to execute such queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Avg()` is an aggregation function, so it operates on a single *oolumn* of values (or a single expression evaluated for each row).  It doesn't take multiple arguments.  You simply want:

```
SELECT (1 + 2 + 3) / 3
```

Contrast this with:

```
SELECT AVG(t.n)
FROM (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3
     ) t
```

This summarizes the three rows into one row, calculating the average.

Comment: That is interesting thing that you leaved `as n` from second and third select within brackets. I tried both WITH `as n` and as you've recommended (WITHOUT `as n`) and both worked.

Comment: @VladaKatlinskaya . . . The column names are taken from the first subquery in a `union all` or `union`.  Having the column names for subsequent subqueries is optional.  I include them when they help make the query more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

In you case you could use avg like this

```
Select avg(data)
From (select 1 as data union 
Select 2 as data union
Select 3 as data) a
```

There are loads of resources on the Internet for learning sql. You should check some of them out.

Hope that helps.